# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))'

Tags: zkemkeeper

I am working with zkemkeeper 64 bit. I am having an error When i ccall
bool a = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IPAddress, Port);

axCZKEM1 is my zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass object.

The following error i am getting.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))'

Can you please help me with this   ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because COM dll files are not registered. you must have something like install.bat, run it in admin mode. Or find the Dll files from the download SDK folder, register all of them, then run the application. Problem will be resolved.